# Why does my prime factorization function append 1 to the result?

Tags: haskell, primes

I am creating a function to factorize any given number in haskell. And so i have created this:

```
primes :: [Integer]
primes = 2:(sieve [3,5..])
    where
        sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x |x <- xs, x `mod` ((p+1) `div` 2 ) > 0]


factorize 2 = [2]
factorize x
    | divisible x = w:(factorize (x `div` w))
    | otherwise   = [x]
    where
          divisible :: Integer -> Bool
          divisible y = [x |x <- (2:[3,5..y]), y `mod` x == 0] /= []

          firstfactor :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
          firstfactor a (x:xs)
              | a `ifdiv` x = x
              | otherwise   = firstfactor a xs
          firstfactor a _ = a

          ifdiv x y = mod x y == 0

          w = firstfactor x primes
```

The function works fine, but appends 1 to the end of the list, for example `factorize 80` would give this list: `[2,2,2,2,5,1]` My question is, why does this happen?

Comment: Obligatory link to "sieve of Erathostenes" paper: http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes up from two parts of the code. Firstly, `factorize 1` is `[1]`. Secondly, since `x` is always divisible by itself, your very final call will always have `w == x`, so the recursion will be `` w:(factorize (w `div` w)) `` which is always `w:(factorize 1)`.

To solve this, you can just add an extra base case to throw out the factors of `1`:

```
factorize 1 = []
factorize ...
```

Also, you can drop the `factorize 2 = [2]` case because it gets subsumed by the `otherwise` case you already have.

`factorize 1 = []` makes sense mathematically, because [`1` has no prime factors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47156/prime-factorization-of-1) (remember that 1 is not a prime number itself!). This follows the same logic behind `product [] = 1`—`1` is the identity for multiplication, which makes it the "default" value when you have nothing to multiply.